# Introducing delay while ajax call in select2 plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, jquery-select2

I am using select 2 example from http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/
I am using "Loading Remote Data" example in this page.

Problem: As soon as I type a letter, system makes an ajax call. I want to introduce delay of 1 second during this request which will allow the user to type his search string.

I am adding code from the site. Please let me know how to introduce delay.

```
("#e6").select2({
            placeholder: "Search for a movie",
            minimumInputLength: 1,
            ajax: { // instead of writing the function to execute the request we use Select2's convenient helper
                url: "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json",
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                data: function (term, page) {
                    return {
                        q: term, // search term
                        page_limit: 10,
                        apikey: "ju6z9mjyajq2djue3gbvv26t" // please do not use so this example keeps working
                    };
                },
                results: function (data, page) { // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
                    // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to alter remote JSON data
                    return {results: data.movies};
                }
            },
            initSelection: function(element, callback) {
                // the input tag has a value attribute preloaded that points to a preselected movie's id
                // this function resolves that id attribute to an object that select2 can render
                // using its formatResult renderer - that way the movie name is shown preselected
                var id=$(element).val();
                if (id!=="") {
                    $.ajax("http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/"+id+".json", {
                        data: {
                            apikey: "ju6z9mjyajq2djue3gbvv26t"
                        },
                        dataType: "jsonp"
                    }).done(function(data) { callback(data); });
                }
            },
            formatResult: movieFormatResult, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
            formatSelection: movieFormatSelection,  // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
            dropdownCssClass: "bigdrop", // apply css that makes the dropdown taller
            escapeMarkup: function (m) { return m; } // we do not want to escape markup since we are displaying html in results
        });
```

Comment: Instead of adding a delay can't you check the number of characters entered by the user ? ex: check weather user has entered more than 3 characters before sending the request ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer to your question is in the actual example you've pointed us to:

```
ajax: {
    url: "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    quietMillis: 100, // <----------- HERE change it to 1000
    data: function (term, page) {
        return {
            q: term, //search term
            page_limit: 10,
            page: page,
            apikey: "ju6z9mjyajq2djue3gbvv26"
        };
    },
    results: function (data, page) {
        var more = (page * 10) < data.total;
        return {results: data.movies, more: more};
    }
},
```

just change the `quietMillis` to something bigger, as the documentation says:

> quietMillis - Number of milliseconds to wait for the user to stop typing before issuing the ajax request

Comment: talsibony's answer is working now. quietMillis is not working new versions

Comment: Agreed this appears to be version specific. quietMillis is respected, but delay is not in select2 3.5.2.

Answer (score 25):

I guess quietMillis property was changed to delay in newer versions of select2:

https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax#rate-limiting-requests

```
$('select').select2({
  ajax: {
    url: '/example/api',
    delay: 250
  }
});
```

Comment: This is the currently correct answer, and I have presumed to add the correct link to the documentation. Not sure why this important configuration is not clearly documented... in the regular documentation of configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Using a utility tool like [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) gives you the ability to use some cool features, like `debounce`!

This exactly solves your problem. `debounce` will postpone its execution until *wait* milliseconds. You can find more info [at the underscore docs](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce)

Comment: true, but you can't really get into the select2 internals to use that here.

Answer (score -1):

You can use setTimeout function:

```
var timer;
...
        initSelection: function(element, callback) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            var id=$(element).val();
            timer = setTimeout(function() {
                if (id!=="") {
                    $.ajax("http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/"+id+".json", {
                        data: {
                            apikey: "ju6z9mjyajq2djue3gbvv26t"
                        },
                        dataType: "jsonp"
                    }).done(function(data) { callback(data); });
                }
            }, 1000);
        },
```